# Where is the installed path location of Java stored when a Java is installed

Tags: java, path, java-web-start, java-ws

My application requires to run javaws.exe. Whereas javaws.exe is missing from java 1.7.151. but instead java 1.8 is installed in which javaws is available.So my application should run in such a way that application runs using JRE of 1.7 whereas it should take javaws of 1.8.So where can i retrieve installed path of JRE 1.8 in windows so that i cant fetch it while using javaws

Comment: Simply configure your env variables. Which IDE you are using?

Comment: But i cant configure the env variables.I want the default location where the path is stored in windows after installation